# First video is stretched on iPad (AVPlayer)

Tags: ios, ipad, video, avplayer

I am working on videos for my App. I am using Avplayer. The videos are playing accurately on all the device except for iPad. It is getting stretched for the very first video. Here is the code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed.video_url];

    cell.videoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    cell.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:cell.videoItem];
    cell.avLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.videoPlayer];
    [cell.avLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [cell.avLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    cell.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[cell.videoPlayer currentItem]];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideMuteImage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [cell.viewForVideo.layer addSublayer:cell.avLayer];

    [cell.videoPlayer play];
```

Please suggest me something. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was view intialising... View was initialising after first cell execution. So, I added before filling table cell and also by setting VideoGravity to AVLayerVideoGravityResize instead of AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill.

```
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        cell.viewForVideo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 5, 480);
    }
```

Thanks anyway.